# Unable to connect to Minecraft servers - iOS 15, 1.17.41, iPhone 13

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

I am experiencing a strange problem with Minecraft on a brand new iPhone 13.

When I am connected to my house wifi everything is ok – I can play on all servers.

But when I try to connect via cellular network or on any other wifi I am getting all possible error messages (some attached below) and can’t connect to any server at all.

Any suggestions welcome!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that app has had the mobile network disabled. It is not obvious and the error message isn’t giving any clues.

in-game Settings > Profile > scroll to ‘Use cellular data’ and turn it on

[image]

re other error messages such as 'Invalid Public key’ which pop-up on various wifi my guess is that the wifi provider is blocking some important ports therefore it is not possible to play minecraft on those networks (also happens on some cellular I think)